# how can i access boolean value to other controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have ProjectSite model and ManagerRemark model related to many to one association. my MangerRemark model has boolean value true and false i want to access that boolean value to other controller view. please help. here is my code.i want to print decision boolean value next to each project site index list how can i do that? in other controller name new_manager_controller view

project_sites_controller.rb

```
class ProjectSitesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :is_project_site?, except: [:show]
  before_action :set_project_site, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /project_sites
  # GET /project_sites.json
  def index
    @project_sites = ProjectSite.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  # GET /project_sites/1
  # GET /project_sites/1.json
  def show
    @manager_remark = ManagerRemark.new
    @manager_remark.project_site_id = @project_site.id

  end

  # GET /project_sites/new
  def new
    @project_site = ProjectSite.new
  end

  # GET /project_sites/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /project_sites
  # POST /project_sites.json
  def create
    @project_site = ProjectSite.new(project_site_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_site.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project_site, notice: 'Project site was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project_site }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project_site.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /project_sites/1
  # PATCH/PUT /project_sites/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_site.update(project_site_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project_site, notice: 'Project site was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project_site }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @project_site.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /project_sites/1
  # DELETE /project_sites/1.json
  def destroy
    @project_site.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to project_sites_url, notice: 'Project site was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project_site
      @project_site = ProjectSite.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters frmanager_level_twoom the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_site_params
      params.require(:project_site).permit(:name, :date, :file)
    end

    def is_project_site?
      redirect_to root_path unless (current_user.role=='project_site')
    end
end
```

This is how my manage remark controller looks.
Manager_Remarks_controller.rb

```
class ManagerRemarksController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @manager_remark = ManagerRemark.new(remark_params)
    @manager_remark.project_site_id = params[:project_site_id]
    @manager_remark.save

    redirect_to project_site_path(@manager_remark.project_site)
  end

  def remark_params
    params.require(:manager_remark).permit(:name, :remark, :decision)
  end

end
```

Comment: So `ProjectSite` has many `manager_remarks`, right? And you want to display `ManagerRemark`'s column value on `project_sites` index, right? Do you want to display all of `ProjectSite`'s `manager_remarks`' values? Or the specific one?

Comment: yes each ProjectSites has many_Remarks. and MangeRemark model has remark field and decision boolean field. i want to access that boolean value on new controller name New_controller.rb with list of project sites along with boolean true false entry. want i need to do changes in old and new controller please help i am new to ruby on rails. thanks!